# ag-Grid lockPosition bug

Tags: ag-grid

Supposedly you should not be able to impact the position of a column with lockPosition set to true. However, if you are persistent and drag a different column in front of it and just hover there for a bit before stopping the drag, it lets you place the unlocked column in front of the locked column. This can be recreated in their demo: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/examples/column-moving/suppress-and-lock/modules/angular/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have also faced this issue. I resolved this by adding lockPinned:true property in defaultColDef